# Unison on MS Windows 10 - cannot connect

Tags: unison

I am trying to set up *unison* to sync to an Ubuntu web server (called "example.com" below) from a Windows 10 PC. I am running unison version 2.48.4 on both computers, and my version of Ubuntu is 18.04 LTS. I am following [this tutorial](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unison-file-synchronizer-tool/).

I have no problems using *ssh* to connect from the PC to the Ububtu server. I.e. `ssh example.com` in PowerShell does what one would expect. However the following command in PowerShell on the PC fails as follows:

```
unison -testserver /tmp/test1 ssh://example.com//tmp/test1
Contacting server...
Fatal error: Error in starting shell connection:
No such file or directory [create_process(ssh)]
```

It looks like unison on the PC is unable to locate *ssh*.

After posting question, I spotted [this workaround on Github](https://github.com/bcpierce00/unison/issues/218). The workaround works, so it may be that this is a bug in this version of *unison*. While I can live with the workaround, I would really appreciate it if someone can point out a way of doing it *without* copying `ssh.exe`.